# Locally submitted transactions to the light node gets lost if the node is restarted

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, light-clients, peers

What happens to the transactions submitted to light node in the following scenarios?
1) Light node does not have a network connection with its peers.I could find that the transactions are submitted successfully to light node but not broadcasted to its peers.
2) Light node is stopped before it can broadcast the transaction submitted.

I could find transactions.rlp file in geth folder for "FULL" nodes. Is this file related to pending transactions somehow? If so, why there is no such file for light client geth and how the transaction queue works for light client? Is it stored internally which is reset on every restarts for a light client?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Light node does not have a network connection with its peers.I
>   could find that the transactions are submitted successfully to light
>   node but not broadcasted to its peers.

I found that by default the Maximum peer count for LES is ZERO then it might be the problem. Can you try to increase LES 1 or 2 peer(s) to see what's happen.

Comment: I am using --lightserv 70 on the full node and its enodeId is added to light client's static nodes file. When the nodes were started, the light client got synced successfully and the transactions were getting submitted and broadcasted. 

The issue of 'not broadcasting transactions' with the light client started after a restart of light node. But then it was importing new blocks successfully. On further restarts, it is observed that those transactions which are not broadcasted earlier is not existing on the light client node as well.(eth.getTransaction() is returning null).

Comment: okay, understand your problem now. I think that it'd better to edit your question then everyone can understand it more clearly ;)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rfikki/e2a8c47f4460668557b1e3ec8bae9c11